# BackgroundImage not showing in JSX?

Tags: javascript, css, image, sass, styles

I'm trying to load this background image in JSX but however, after all attempts images WILL NOT load.

The Row component is from ReactStrap and I'm using WebPack.

I've tried backgroundColor and the color rendered fine.

I've tried all combinations of quotes and template literals.

I've tried not using the `<row />` component and simply using style on a regular div, still no luck.

I've tried inline and in a separate object in a variable.

I've tried using ref.

the png image is in the same folder as the js file.

in Chrome Dev Tools the image looks like it's loaded on the containers fine.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<Row style={{ backgroundImage: `url('./leigh.png')` }} key={props.id} className={postCardWithBG}>
</Row>
```

With Div:

the className="div" just there to give width and height to the div.

```
<div className="div" style={{ backgroundImage: `url('./leigh.png')` }}></div>
</div>
```

A more full code example:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import '../scss/base.scss'
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { CardTitle, CardText, Row, Col } from "reactstrap"
import Moment from "react-moment"
import UserBar from './UserBar/UserBar'
import ThumbUp from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUp';
import AddCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircle';
import Place from '@material-ui/icons/Place'

const PostCard = props => {

    let Background = './leigh.png'

    return (
        <>
          <div className="div" style={{ backgroundImage: `url('./leigh.png')` }}></div>
            <Row style={{ backgroundImage: `url('./leigh.png')` }} key={props.id} className={postCardWithBG}>
            </Row>
          </div>
        </>
     )
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using require('./path-to-image') for the image src.

```
const background = require('./leigh.png');

<div className="div" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${background})` }}></div>
```

Comment: I could kiss you. Thank you.